# Javascript and AJAX using session objects, only works when using alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I ran in the following problem while implementing show/hide of a div in my html.

This show/hide is governed by a variable say id, which I am storing and retrieving using session objects (using sessionAware in Struts 2).

My problem is following, even though I see that id variable is properly set in Java end, it is not working in JavaScript part. 
On introducing the alerts around the reading of id variable is script, this works fine.

Can someone help me how to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Put some code snippet what you have tried.

Comment: @Vivek show the javaScript code

Comment: I shall post the code base in sometime as at this moment I am away from my workstation. Many thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

It look like data load issue.

I assume like when you check for the value data is not loaded, and the check fails.

When you put an alert into it, the page pauses on alert, during that time the data loads and then you get it correctly then.

It is only an assumption based on what you provided.

Please provide some sample code or snipets.

Comment: I shall post the code base in sometime as at this moment I am away from my workstation. Many thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

There are a few functions that stop the code from running when they are called. This are called synchronous functions causing a pause in the code until you click OK. alert() is synchronous and so is prompt().

Till that time your data may be loaded, It my just opinion on the base of desc given.

regards,